# C Function to Convert a Binary Tree into its Mirror Tree

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

How to convert a tree to its mirror tree. For eg.

```
    1                     1
   / \                   / \
  2   3        to       3   2
 /                           \
4                             4
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366251/mirror-image-of-a-binary-tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform post order traversal.

```
void mirror(struct node* node) 
{
  if (node!=NULL)
  {
    struct node* temp;

    /* do the subtrees */
    mirror(node->left);
    mirror(node->right);

    /* swap the pointers in this node */
    temp        = node->left;
    node->left  = node->right;
    node->right = temp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Solution uses recursion to convert a tree to its mirror tree.
>
> 1. If root of both trees are null, then they are same. Return true.
> 2. If roots of both the trees are not null, check if the data in the two nodes is same and recursively check if left and right subtrees are identical.
> 3. If the roots of only one of the trees is null, then the trees are not identical, so return false.

Source: http://www.ideserve.co.in/learn/mirror-a-tree