# Mirror a binary tree

Tags: java, tree

I have a simple Node class to construct a tree node in my binary tree:

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    public Node(int i) {
        this.data = i;
    }
}
```

I've written a simple Tree class which will use the Node structure to build a tree:

```
class Tree {
    Node root;
}
```

I'm trying to write a recursive function **mirror()** in my Tree class that will return a mirrored version of the tree (left and right nodes swapped).

So if I call this function on a Tree t, I would expect to start from the root, and swap all of the nodes until we reach a node that has no more children to swap. The part I'm struggling with is after we've swapped the root nodes children, how I can recursively call the mirror function on these nodes and then return the mirrored tree.

As you can see, the code below will swap the root node's children, but after that I am stuck as I can't call the mirror function on nodes, only a tree.

```
public Tree mirror() {
    Node temp = this.root.left;
    this.root.left = this.root.right;
    this.root.right = temp;
```

If you could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Can't you just traverse your tree from right to left instead of left to right? With the same tree you can traverse it ASC or DESC.

Comment: You should make the mirror method to accept a node, not the whole tree. This way, you can call it recursively on right and left elements.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366251/mirror-image-of-a-binary-tree

Comment: Hint: you have to do this in a recursive way(pass node as a parameter to the function) or do it iteratively(using stacks)

Comment: @ClaudiuGuja I would do that, but what if I want to simply call tree.mirror() to get the mirrored tree? If it accepts a node then I have to call mirror(node) which seems tedious since I will have to create a new node object

Answer (score 3):

You need a separate method that will accept `Node` object, mirror its children and call itself recursively.

```
public Tree mirror() {
    mirrorInternal(this.root);
    return this;
}

private void mirrorInternal(Node node) {
    Node tmp = node.left;
    node.left = node.right;
    node.right = tmp;
    if (node.left != null) {
        mirrorInternal(node.left);
    }
    if (node.right != null) {
        mirrorInternal(node.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. Would this be the most efficient way to approach something like this? Can it not be done in one method?

Comment: @juyebgastro this is the easiest way. Since it would be a single method that needs to accept objects of different types additional coding might be required in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could also change your Node-class such that it uses a flag for mirrored behavior:

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node[] children;

    public Node(int i) {
        this.data = i;
        this.children = new Node[2];
    }

    public void setLeft(Node node) {
        children[0] = node;
    }

    public void setRight(Node node) {
        children[1] = node;
    }

    public Node getLeft(boolean mirrored) {
        return mirrored ? children[1] : children[0];
    }

    public Node getRight(boolean mirrored) {
        return mirrored ? children[0] : children[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void mirror (Tree tree) {
  mirror (tree.root);
}

Node mirror (Node node) {
  if (node != null) {
    Node temp = node.left;
    node.left = mirror (node.right);
    node.right = mirror (temp);
  }
  return node;
}
```